# UWP convert Image to string

Tags: image, bluetooth, uwp

I am trying to send  an Image object via bluetooth using the
BluetoothRfcommChat sample
my idea is to convert the image to string before sending and converting it back when received. 
my question is how to convert an Image to String

```
                string message;
                //here should go the conversion
                //message=myimg;
                writer.WriteUInt32((uint)message.Length);
                writer.WriteString(message);


                ConversationListBox.Items.Add(myimg);


                await writer.StoreAsync();
```

or which will be the "Right" way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not do it because tring are null terminated. Any 0 in data indicates end of string.
2. You should send it as raw bytes.
3. To send image, music or any other file (object) over Bluetooth special protocol was developed. It is called OBEX and ObjectPushProfile is designed to send such things. This is what the right way to send files.

Comment: Thanks , is there any sample to guide me from?

Comment: I afraid thewre is no example for UWP so you have to implement OBEX by your self. For Classic Desktop: 32feet or Bluetooth Frameowrk. Both includes OPP support.